# Triangle Matrices

Tags: matrices

Let A = ($a_{dj}$)$_{n × n}$ and B = ($b_{dj}$)$_{n × n}$ be two upper triangular matrices, i.e $a_{ij}$ = $b_{ij}$ whenever i>j

Find the (i,i) entry of AB.

I've done
$(AB)_{ii}$ = $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{ik}b_{ki} $$

But I'm not exactly sure how to split the summation so as to simplify the summation expression using triangle matrices properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upper triangle matrices are such that $a_{ij} = 0$ whenever $i>j$.
So let's take back your sum, and split it by cases over the value of $k$ : $k < i$, $k = i$ and $k > i$.

\begin{align}
(AB)_{ii} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{ik}b_{ki} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} a_{ik}b_{ki} + a_{ii}b_{ii} + \sum_{k=i+1}^{n} a_{ik}b_{ki}
\end{align}

But in the first sum, any $k < i$, thus any $a_{ik} = 0$ and in the third sum, any $k > i$, thus any $b_{ki} = 0$.  Therefore the first and third cases sum to $0$ so the result is :
$$
(AB)_{ii} = a_{ii}b_{ii}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $k\neq i$, then either $a_{ik}$ or $b_{ki}$ must be zero.